# PowerShell Azure Blob Snapshot Retention

Tags: powershell, azure

I would like to manage my blob snapshots in azure with a PowerShell script.

I already have a script which creates every hour a snapshot from a blob.

Now I would like to create a query that deletes old snapshots.

If the snapshot is older than 5 days, the last snapshot of the day is to be retained. All snapshots older than 30 days are to be deleted.

How can I do this?

My code which deletes all snapshots after 30 days:

```
foreach ($CloudBlockBlob in $ListOfBlobs)
    {
      if ($CloudBlockBlob.IsSnapshot)
      {
        if ($CloudBlockBlob.SnapshotTime.DateTime -le $RetentionTime )
        {
          $CloudBlockBlob.Delete()
          if (!$?) { Write-Host "Snapshot cannot be deleted. Error on Line " + Get-CurrentLineNumber }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this script to delete snapshot blob older than 5 days:

```
$deletetime = [datetime]::today.adddays(-5).tostring('yyyyMMdd')
$StorageAccountName = "jasondisk3"
$StorageAccountKey = "m+kQwLuQZiI3LMoMTyAI8dq4qul4s8fAIHGPMTD/AG2j+TPHBpttq5hXRmTaQ=="
$ContainerName = "jasonvm" 
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$ListBlob = Get-AzureStorageBlob –Context $Ctx -Container $ContainerName | Where-Object {$_.ICloudBlob.IsSnapshot -and $_.SnapshotTime -ne $null -and (($_.SnapshotTime.localdatetime).ToString('yyyyMMdd') -lt $deletetime) }
foreach($b in $listblob) {
$b.ICloudBlob.Delete()
}
```

Note:

This PowerShell will delete all blobs in that container and older than 5 days.

---

**Update**:

Here a script to delete one day's snapshots and keep the latest one, please refer to it:

```
$deletetime = [datetime]::today.adddays(-1).tostring('yyyyMMdd')
$StorageAccountName = "jasondisk3"
$StorageAccountKey = "m+kQwLuQZiI3LMoMTyAI8K40gkOD+ZaTxxxs8fAIHGPMTD/AG2j+TPHBpttq5hXRmTaQ=="
$ContainerName = "jasonvm" 
$Ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey
$a = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $ContainerName -Context $Ctx | select -ExpandProperty name -Unique
foreach($c in $a){$d = $c.split('.')[0]; $e = $d +'*' ; $f = Get-AzureStorageBlob –Context $Ctx -Container $ContainerName -blob $e | Where-Object {$_.ICloudBlob.IsSnapshot -and $_.SnapshotTime -ne $null -and (($_.SnapshotTime.localdatetime).ToString('yyyyMMdd') -eq '20171110') }; $ff = $f[-1];foreach($qq in $f){if($qq -ne $ff){$qq.ICloudBlob.Delete()}} }
```

You can modify it to delete other days, add a `foreach` to date.

Hope this helps:)

Comment: Thanks. But i would like to make two filters. If there are Snapshots there older than 5 days i would like to keep the only the first Snapshot (e.g. from day 6,7,8,...)

Comment: @fb_luc Do you mean you want to keep snapshot for every day? just keep one snapshot for every day?

Comment: yes, right. All of day 1-4 completely kept. All snapshots older than 5 days are only kept one per day (best is latest from day e.g. night). All snapshots older than 30 days will be completely deleted.  Thank you very much

Comment: Please let me know if you need more help?